# Using Flask Blueprints, how to fix url_for from breaking if a subdomain is specified?

Tags: python, routes, flask

Inside of a flask blueprint, i have:

```
frontend = Blueprint('frontend', __name__)
```

and the route to my index function is:

```
@frontend.route('/')
def index():
  #code
```

This works fine but, I am trying to add a subdomain to the route, like so:

```
@frontend.route('/', subdomain='<var>')
def index(var):
```

But this breaks the app and the browser spits out (amongst other things):

```
werkzeug.routing.BuildError
BuildError: ('frontend.index', {}, None)
```

frontend.index is called out in my code in a few places in a *url_for('frontend.index')*

How can I get the url_for to work when I'm including a subdomain? The only thing in the documents I can find and I think might be relevant is this under http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/:

> To integrate applications, Flask has a hook to intercept URL build
>   errors through Flask.build_error_handler. The url_for function results
>   in a BuildError when the current app does not have a URL for the given
>   endpoint and values. When it does, the current_app calls its
>   build_error_handler if it is not None, which can return a string to
>   use as the result of url_for (instead of url_for‘s default to raise
>   the BuildError exception) or re-raise the exception. An example:

```
def external_url_handler(error, endpoint, **values):
    "Looks up an external URL when `url_for` cannot build a URL."
    # This is an example of hooking the build_error_handler.
    # Here, lookup_url is some utility function you've built
    # which looks up the endpoint in some external URL registry.
    url = lookup_url(endpoint, **values)
    if url is None:
        # External lookup did not have a URL.
        # Re-raise the BuildError, in context of original traceback.
        exc_type, exc_value, tb = sys.exc_info()
        if exc_value is error:
            raise exc_type, exc_value, tb
        else:
            raise error
    # url_for will use this result, instead of raising BuildError.
    return url

app.build_error_handler = external_url_handler
```

However, I am new to python (and programming) and can not understand where I would put this code or how I would get that function to call when a builderror occurs.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tried adding ``_external=True`` to your url_for() call?

Comment: @chrickso: See my answer. It looks like, you just need to provide different method names.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, to use subdomains you need to have a value for the SERVER_NAME [configuration](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/config/):

```
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'example.net'
```

You have a view like this:

```
frontend = Blueprint('frontend', __name__)
@frontend.route('/', subdomain='<var>')
def index(var):
    return ...
```

In order to reconstruct the URL to this view, Flask needs a value for *var*. `url_for('frontend.index')` will fail since it does not have enough values. With the above SERVER_NAME, `url_for('frontend.index', var='foo')` will return `http://foo.example.net/`.

Answer (score 11):

Add blueprint name in `url_for`. Example:

```
url_for('pay_sermepa.sermepa_cancel', _external=True)
```

- `pay_sermepa`: blueprint name
- `sermepa_cancel`: route

Answer (score -4):

I don't think this is an issue with Flask.

You are providing two functions with the same method name:

```
@frontend.route('/')
def index():
  #code
```

and

```
@frontend.route('/', subdomain='<var>')
def index(var):
```

They are wrapped differently but when flask.build_url is called, it is throwing because of overloaded function name.
This seems incorrect on first glance.

Try providing a different function name for the second one like

```
@frontend.route('/', subdomain='<var>')
def index_var(var):
```

This may solve your issue. I haven't tested it though.