# Multiple subdomains allowed in the same blueprint

Tags: python, flask, subdomain, blueprint

I need to have two sub domains allowed in this blueprint. In this case, pt and br. How can i do that? As far as i know, i can only have a sub-domain parameter. I want to use this function for both languages [pt and br].

```
mod = Blueprint('landing', __name__, url_prefix='/', subdomain='pt')

@mod.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    pass
```

I want to avoid [dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11694171/564979) sub-domains because I don't want to change all my `url_for()`.

Answer (score 6):

Don't define the blueprint's prefix and subdomain where you are doing it currently, define it like so:

```
mod = Blueprint('landing', __name__)
```

Then, simply register the blueprint two times, one for each subdomain:

```
app.register_blueprint(mod, subdomain='pt', url_prefix='/')
app.register_blueprint(mod, subdomain='br', url_prefix='/')
```

**EDIT:**

The problem with the given solution, as stated by OP, is that the first registered blueprint will take priority when using `url_for` in templates.

A quick workaround could be doing something like this when registering:

```
app.register_blueprint(mod, subdomain='br')
mod.name = 'landing_pt'    
app.register_blueprint(mod, subdomain='pt')
```

Note that the order this is done with is important (first register one, then change the name, then register the other one).

Then, for `url_for` to work as expected with both subdomains, it is important to use [relative redirects](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/blueprints/#building-urls) like `url_for('.index')` instead of `url_for('landing.index')`.

By changing the name of the blueprint for the second registration we trick Flask into thinking this is a different blueprint.

Suggestions welcome to better this kind of dirty workaround.

Comment: this will cause an huge bunch of problems. The order of registration will break all links due the prefix. Always assume the link with the prefix of the first subdomain registered. I will use a config file per VM and solve this issue.

Comment: @andv I think I understand what your problem is. The first registered subdomain takes priority when using url_for. I just edited the answer with a workaround for this problem. Hope it helps.